# Android Slide Animation within layout

Tags: java, android, animation, layout

How can I do this animation in my activity?

when you click a button in the layout, it will slide like this(can't post too many links and picture yet

I already tried doing tabbed but its not the one i'm looking for.
its my first time doing, I only know how to have slide animation between activity

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT***

I want to know how to get this effect

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJtFw.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a fragment for the central layout and then use Fragment animations like this

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
DetailsFragment newFragment = DetailsFragment.newInstance();
ft.replace(R.id.details_fragment_container, newFragment, "detailFragment");
ft.commit();
```

Where the xml file for animation could look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
  <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:propertyName="x" 
android:valueType="floatType"
android:valueFrom="-1280"
android:valueTo="0" 
android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

There are many other animations you can apply, you can find more resources [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

Comment: can you explain it more, sorry i couldn't understand, its my first time to use fragments and animations within layouts

Comment: Let's say everything is contained in an Activity, the layout file for the activity contains Layout1 a FrameLayout and Layout 2. In the example code i gave you FrameLayout has id details_fragment_container. Then you add Fragments to that FrameLayout using the code above. Tab1 and Tab2 are Fragments, imagine them as a more advanced View. You can attach them to your FrameLayout and swap/move/stack them. have a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I suggest you start with learning about fragments and how to use them, https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html it's a very important part of the Android system and you will need to use it in many situations. Once you have that you can apply animation transitions to have and go back to creating the the layout you are working on now.

Comment: i think we are talking to a different things here i misinterpreted it, the example you gave is different to what i'm looking for, its also different from the links that you have given

Comment: Ok now I see what you need, the component to do that it's a ViewPager http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html